# Failed to upload blob file to S3 using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I used connect-multiparty middlewhere and I have below code:

```
console.log(req.files)

      var data = {
        Key: req.body.filename,
        Body: req.files,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
      };


      s3Bucket.putObject(data,function(err,result){
        console.log(err);
      });
```

And I got below result in my terminal:

```
{ photo: 
   { fieldName: 'photo',
     originalFilename: 'blob',
     path: '/var/folders/n1/fr69rt5j01sfwjhsh3jx3gh00000gn/T/Tw4pwoPQ5D7zCGxrk3U1ywKp',
     headers: 
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="photo"; filename="blob"',
        'content-type': 'image/jpeg' },
     size: 50138,
     name: 'blob',
     type: 'image/jpeg' } }
{ [InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object]
  message: 'Expected params.Body to be a string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object',
  code: 'InvalidParameterType',
```

Any clue this doesn't work? What should be `Body`'s value?

Answer (score 6):

If you have base64 format of image you can use below method.

The parameters to this is

1.**image** : base64 format of image

2.**FileName** : name of the file in string Eg: 'name.jpg'

```
var UploadFilesToS3 = function(image,FileName) {  //
    buf = new Buffer(image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64');
    var data = {
        Key: FileName,
        Body: buf,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    s3Bucket.putObject(data,function (data,err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log('failed to Upload: '+ err.body);
        }
    });
};
```

And also you need to make AWS configuration before calling this method like this

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: '',
        secretAccessKey: '',
        region: ''
    });

var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3( { params: {Bucket: 'name of the bucket'} } );
```

Comment: where is the image come from?

Comment: Image is the photo that you need to upload

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @Suprajv

Comment: Great answer. Do you know why we have to convert it to a buffer and we can't just upload it as a string? I believe the AWS `putObject` method accepts `body` as a `string, Buffer, Stream, Blob, or typed array object`.

Answer (score 0):

The `req.files` is not the thing you need to upload, try this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var photo = req.files.photo
var data = {
  Key: req.body.filename,
  Body: fs.createReadStream(photo.path),
  ContentType: photo.type
};

s3Bucket.putObject(data, function (err, result) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log(result);
});
```